# Can't create a demo for an Azure firewall using CLI?

Tags: azure, networking, firewall, azure-cli

I'm not very good at computer networking, but was asked to document an Azure CLI script example to create a firewall. Below is my script. It worked on my local machine and private account. But when I moved it to another account it was no longer working correctly. It is simply to create a firewall and allow a backend VM to connect to Github by a configuration change. But that last `ping` step is giving me a `ping: https://github.com: Name or service not known` error.

What could be wrong with my configuration CLI below?

```
az group create --name $resource --location eastus

az extension add --name azure-firewall

az network vnet create \
  --name lesson28VN \
  --subnet-name AzureFirewallSubnet \
  --address-prefix 10.0.0.0/16 \
  --subnet-prefix 10.0.1.0/26 \
  --location eastus \
  --resource-group $resource 

az network vnet create \
  --name lesson28VN \
  --subnet-name AzureFirewallSubnet \
  --address-prefix 10.0.0.0/16 \
  --subnet-prefix 10.0.1.0/26 \
  --location eastus \
  --resource-group $resource 

az network vnet subnet create \
  --name workloadSubnet \
  --vnet-name lesson28VN  \
  --address-prefix 10.0.2.0/24 \
  --resource-group $resource 

az network vnet subnet create \
   --name jumpSubnet \
   --vnet-name lesson28VN \
   --address-prefix 10.0.3.0/24 \
   --resource-group $resource

az vm create \
    --name jumpVM \
    --image UbuntuLTS \
    --location eastus \
    --resource-group $resource\
    --vnet-name lesson28VN \
    --subnet jumpSubnet \
    --admin-username azureuser \
    --generate-ssh-keys 

az vm open-port \
    --name jumpVM \
    --port 22 \
    --resource-group $resource

az network public-ip create \
  --name workPublicIp \
  --allocation-method Static \
  --resource-group $resource \
  --sku Standard

az network nic create \
   --name workNIC \
   --vnet-name lesson28VN \
   --subnet workloadSubnet \
   --public-ip-address workPublicIp \
   --resource-group $resource 

az vm create \
    --name workVM \
    --image UbuntuLTS \
    --location eastus \
    --nics workNIC \
    --resource-group $resource \
    --admin-username azureuser \
    --generate-ssh-keys 

az network firewall create \
    --name myFirewall \
    --resource-group $resource \
    --location eastus

az network public-ip create \
    --name firewallPublicIP \
    --resource-group $resource \
    --location eastus \
    --allocation-method static \
    --sku standard

az network firewall ip-config create \
    --name firewallConfig \
    --firewall-name myFirewall \
    --public-ip-address firewallPublicIP \
    --resource-group $resource \
    --vnet-name lesson28VN

az network firewall update \
    --name myFirewall \
    --resource-group $resource 

az network public-ip show \
    --name firewallPublicIP \
    --resource-group $resource

firewallPrivateIp=$(az network firewall ip-config list \
    --resource-group $resource \
    --firewall-name myFirewall \
    --query "[?name=='firewallConfig'].privateIpAddress" \
    --output tsv)

az network route-table create \
    --name firewallRouteTable \
    --location eastus \
    --resource-group $resource \
    --disable-bgp-route-propagation true

az network route-table route create \
  --name myFirewallRoute \
  --route-table-name firewallRouteTable \
  --address-prefix 0.0.0.0/0 \
  --resource-group $resource \
  --next-hop-type VirtualAppliance \
  --next-hop-ip-address $firewallPrivateIp

az network vnet subnet update \
    --name workloadSubnet \
    --resource-group $resource \
    --vnet-name lesson28vn \
    --address-prefixes 10.0.2.0/24 \
    --route-table firewallRouteTable

az network firewall application-rule create \
   --firewall-name myFirewall \
   --name allowGithub \
   --collection-name myAppCollection1 \
   --target-fqdns www.github.com \
   --protocols Http=80 Https=443 \
   --resource-group $resource \
   --source-addresses 10.0.2.0/24 \
   --priority 280 \
   --action Allow

az network firewall network-rule create \
   --destination-addresses 209.244.0.3 209.244.0.4 \
   --destination-ports 53 \
   --firewall-name myFirewall \
   --collection-name myNetCollection1 \
   --name allowDNS \
   --protocols UDP \
   --resource-group $resource \
   --priority 280 \
   --source-addresses 10.0.2.0/24 \
   --action Allow

workIp=$(az vm show -d --resource-group $resource --name workVm --query publicIps -o tsv)
echo $workIP # don't know why NIC is not picking up the IP address? 

jumpIp=$(az vm show -d --resource-group $resource --name jumpVm --query publicIps -o tsv)
ssh azureuser@$jumpIp
```

And then from that machine I jump into the backend:

```
ssh azureuser@{PUT WORK IP ADDRESS HERE}

ping https://github.com # Name or service not known
```

Comment: Ping isn't going to work like that. Try pinging just `github.com`

Answer (score 0):

The ping command use ICMP protocol not HTTP protocol.
You dont have to put the "https://"
You can only ping an IP or a domain name
If you want to ping " https://github.com # Name or service not known" just use ping github.com or ping 192.30.255.113
ping is a powefull command you can use with many arguments.
If you want to learn more just check https://www.lifewire.com/ping-command-2618099